# Pods folder not showing under Git tracking

Tags: xcode, git, github, git-commit, git-push

I am trying to add one of my folder called as Pods - Its for iOS and not showing under Git tracking
I have used below command to check

```
Git status
```

To check the current tracking status but not getting help
I have checked the current tracking files by using the command

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD
```

And the folder getting list as "Pods"
But It's not getting the push on the branch and not showing in git status
I have also tried to check /info/exclude file but this is already blank so no chance to ignore

[image]

After applying `git log --stat -- Pods`
It shows me like 
`Pods | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)`

Answer (score 0):

`git status` will only show changed or untracked files. Your `Pods` directory is probably already committed and therefore tracked.

Try `git log --stat -- Pods`.

Comment: @js It's showing like this     

 Pods | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

Comment: @KirtikumarA. Can you make sure that info is in the question?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes I have added into question, do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: There is no “solution” this question explains why you don’t see the folder in `git status`. Change a file in the folder and you’ll see it appear there once again.